# Converting from 8 bits to 1 byte

Tags: c++, byte, bit-shift

I have a string of 8 bits and I want to convert it into 1 byte. I am not sure why my function is not working properly. I have 8 bits stored into an array of 8 unsigned chars. This is my method so far:

```
unsigned int bitsToBytes(unsigned char *bits)
{
  unsigned int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    sum += bits[i];
    sum<<=1;
  }
  return sum;

}

int main()
{
  unsigned char bits[8];
  unsigned int byt;
  byt = bitsToBytes(bits);
  cout << byt; //doesn't give me the right result
}
```

EDIT: My array of bits contains '1' and '0' in the array! Sorry for not being clear.

Might anyone know where I went wrong in this? I'm not sure why my bits aren't converting to bytes properly. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: In your example, you aren't putting anything into `bits`.

Comment: What results are you expecting? Because you shouldn't have any expectations about the output of the shown code due to the fact that you don't initialized `bits`.

Comment: Also note that you need to do the shift before adding the bit.

Comment: @VaughnCato Yep, good find? May I incorporate this in my answer?

Comment: @H2CO3: sure, nice of you to ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sum += bits[i];
```

If you're trying to convert a C *string* (for example, `"1010101"`), this code adds the codetable value (ASCII, UTF-8, whichever encoding you have) of the char (for example, 48 and 49), not `1` and `0`. You should rewrite this as

```
sum += bits[i] - '0';
```

Also, you don't initialize the `bits` array - using its contents before initialization results in undefined behavior, so you can expact *anything* to happen.

Furthermore, your code logic is flawed - One, you have to do the left shift **before** adding the binary digit. Two, you're traversing the string backwards; the line

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
```

should really be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

Comment: Ah great this helps! However, I'm still printing the wrong values... and I'm not sure why unfortunately. For example: I have the following in my unsigned char bits = 10100101 which should give me a decimal value of 165. However, when I print byt, I get 330. Also when I put in something like 00110000 which should give me a decimal value of 30, I get 24. Any ideas?

Comment: @user200081 330 is two times 165. Did you move the shift before the addition as I suggested? Doesn't seem so.

Comment: Hm, will it make any difference in that my array has of '1's and '0's as opposed to 1 and 0? Also if I move the shift before the addition then my screen prints out a bunch of blank characters...

Comment: @user200081 "that my array has of '1's and '0's as opposed to 1 and 0" - now read my answer again.

Comment: @user200081 Also, you have another error - you're stepping through the string upside-down...

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! That fixed everything! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

This should work properly, under normal situations.

What does the char[] contain? Does it contain '0', '1' instead of 0, 1?

To make sure, change line

```
sum += bits[i];
```

to

```
sum |= bits[i] & 1;
```

Also, as pointed out by Vaughn Cato in comments, you need to shift *before* adding.

Comment: This relies on the character code of `0` and `1` being even and odd, respectively (works only by chance if ASCII is assumed).

Comment: Yes, I assumed C/cpp ascii... Since the question was tagged as C++ & it was simple char, not wchar_t. Another option would be to subtract '0', but I was not sure, if his array contained 1, or '1'; I mean, whether that was the real issue in his case.

Comment: My array contains '1' and '0' so sorry for confusing you!

Comment: So it'd contain:
    sum<<=1;
    sum += bits[i]-'0';
    
?

Comment: If you are sure you are always going to use '1' & '0' & never 1 & 0, then, this should be good enough. If there is a possibility of using 0, 1, '0', '1' all interleaved, use `bits[i] & 1` (should work for standard char in c/cpp).

Answer (score -1):

If any one is still interested in converting bits to bytes check out this gist.  I prepared it as a sketch for the Arduino so that I can send out the electrical pulses that represent each byte.  I used arrays of int instead of character but the concept is the same.  Considering the size of those types, I may soon switch it to byte or char.

in particular take a look at the encodeByte and decodeByte functions

Sketch for transmitting bits [gist](https://gist.github.com/fernandozamoraj/530ee4e4fd0d5d413dbb)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t aa=0x41; 
    printf("%c",aa);  //A
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.